# auto increment after delete from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: Reorder/Reset auto increment primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key)

if I delete from my table a ligne and in this table i have an auto increment ID , 
DELETE From table where id=2

after this the table will be like this

```
 ID   | NAme
1        aaa
3        cccc
```

how can i fix the ID to be like this

```
ID   | NAme
1        aaa
2        cccc
3        dddd
```

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do this, ID is auto incremented for a reason.

Comment: Most certainly, you wouldn't want to do that. It could lead to dangerous confusions...

Comment: +1 for the really good question

Comment: This has a serious drawback, you or the DBMS has to reorganize all records after the deleted record. Not only that, if ID is your primary key, all dependant tables also need to be updated (in order to keep referential integrity). In general [primary keys should never change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337503/whats-the-best-practice-for-primary-keys-in-tables/338424#338424).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this answer: [Reorder / reset auto increment primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key)

Comment: I think this is wrong way of doing things. Wrong database design comes in mind. Never needed to re-assing autoincrement fields.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.  Should be voted a duplicate question.

Comment: it's not a solution. bad practice !

Answer (score 0):

Autoincrement doesn't work this way. If you have 2 records on table with ID-s 1 and 2 and you delete the record with ID 2, then the next will always will be still 3.

Suggest you to add additional column with holding those values for the reasons you need it for.

Also, I learned in school long time ago, that in great systems, never records are deleted. There's a column holding timestamp value that marks them as "deleted".

Comment: Soft-delete is a design decision, and not a rule.  It is most often there to support data warehousing.