# SQL regenerate ID to keep autoincrement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for pure SQL (or MySQL) syntax and I don't know if it's possible else I will create an php script but ...

I have a basic table with one primary key : ID and somes columns. I have no dependance with others tables.

At the moment my rows look like :

```
ID   Column1   Column2  
22   test      test
26   test2     test2
33   test3     test3
...
```

Now I want to regenerate all my ID to keep order. Example: I set start at 22

```
ID   Column1   Column2  
22   test      test
23   test2     test2
24   test3     test3
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Reorder/Reset auto increment primary key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key)

Comment: Side note: `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not a good choice for identifiers that do have a meaning. For instance, you have to issue a DML query just to reset it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go and look there : [Reorder / reset auto increment primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key)

But as said there it will ruined the relationship you already have. But since you don't it's ok

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP `id`;
ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

Comment: btw first google answer for "reorder auto increment", which is faster to type than ask the question ???

Comment: How does this guarantee the order is kept?

Comment: It doesn't. But it wasn't the question. And since there is no relationship it's ok.

Comment: "I want to regenerate all my ID to keep order". Never mind, he seems happy with the answer :)

Comment: To keep order in this sentence means to keep the numbers ordered as in 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 (at least it's how I understand it)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be to create a new table with your desired auto_increment column then

```
INSERT INTO myNewTable (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM myOldTable
ORDER BY ID
```