# Re-index table in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table in my database that I would like to re-index.

Because some rows where deleted, I now have :

```
id     name      phone
1      xxxx      xxxxx
4      xxxx      xxxxx
6      xxxx      xxxxx
```

And I would like:

```
id     name      phone
1      xxxx      xxxxx
2      xxxx      xxxxx
3      xxxx      xxxxx
```

`id` is already auto-incremented.
The change of id for a row won't have any impact on the rest of the site, it's just a single and very simple customer list.

I've searched on internet and found some things with REPAIR TABLE but I'm not sure it's adapted to my case :/

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What database are you using? What column you want to re-index? What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I have some id that doesn't exist anymore because the line was deleted. I would prefer to have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead of 1, 2, 6, 9, 10.  I want to reset the indexes and re-create them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove gaps in auto increment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9754244/1427878). You should pay special attention to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28507586/1427878), in particular the external page it links to in the first paragraph.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not intended for such use.  If you want particular numbers, generate them yourself.  Gaps do no hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

I have a table called `Events` that has these fields where the `id` field is primary key and auto incremented:

```
id
EventType
DateTime
Weight
Comment
```

To 're-index' the table I did things in this order:

1. Created new table based on old tables structure
2. Copy records into new table **WITHOUT the id field** from old table, sorting by old tables id field
3. Drop old table
4. Rename new table to old table name

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE NewEvents LIKE Events;
INSERT INTO NewEvents (EventType, DateTime, Weight, Comment) SELECT EventType, DateTime, Weight, Comment FROM Events ORDER BY id;
DROP TABLE Events;
RENAME TABLE NewEvents TO Events;
```

The second command that copies the records over to the new table is what re-creates the new index numbers. And because the records are sorted by the id field of the old table, it will ignore any missing id numbers and just keep auto-incrementing the new tables id field.

It worked for me anyways, but I highly recommend testing this from a complete copy of the entire schema then testing with your app to make sure everything works properly before doing this on a live / production schema.

I've never used TRIGGERS before, so I'm not sure if creating a table that is LIKE another table actually re-creates the triggers or not., nor am I sure if it re-creates any foreign key relationships. My gut says that these things will NOT be re-created, but in my case, this didn't matter. The point is, don't do this haphazardly - TEST TEST TEST on non-production data before doing this and BE THOROUGH!