# Fix auto increment mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: Reorder/Reset auto increment primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key)

I have an auto increment field in my sql, by accident i deleted something now my tables are off because the auto increment number jumped. I forgot the exact sql command but i remember there was an Select table set auto increment='whatever' i just forgot the syntax, can anyone help?

Comment: What does "off" mean - is there just a gap?

Comment: I am getting the vibe from your question that it is significant the auto increment is in order.  If so, why?

Comment: because when i made my database i was stupid enough to do it that way =( in the mean time i need to fix the issue before i redo my schema

Comment: It happens to the best of us, we are all learning.  I would recommend doing a dump of the database and testing any commands against a local instance to avoid further corruption.

Comment: yeah i mean i was NEW NEW to programming and my db is now huge so like to do it over again is BLAH one of those things, ill get around to it though eventually, and i think i should maybe start on a fresh server so i dont patch up crap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE theTableInQuestion AUTO_INCREMENT=1234
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT=YOUR_DESIRED_NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 1):

See Below:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = newNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

```
ALTER table drop column autoinc_column;
ALTER table add column autoinc_column ...;
```

Where "..." is the same parameters used to create the initial column.

Comment: More work then is needed, you can just reassign a value to AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: This is what must be done if you are trying to redo the auto increment instead of just resetting the auto increment number