# How to update the id column starting from 1 again

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem to update the list of id number again starting from 1,2,3,4,5. Since I have deleted few records as I was testing the sql commands. Can you please help on how to make this id column again starting from 1.

I could just the name of the id number however if I do that then when I input new record, it will again start from the previous number which was 66.

```
ID    Name 

1   A

32  B

34  C

35  D

55  E

66  F
```

Comment: Since they are all auto-incrementing, You have to empty or truncate the table

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key

Comment: @ntgCleaner, You mean replace them manually?

Comment: *Don't* do this. An auto-increment surrogate PK *does not* imply sequential order. It's better for the database clustering to simply let the auto-increment PK just keep increment as normal.

Comment: @user2864740 It seems that Sandesh is done with his testing and needs to reset his table to start fresh with real date.  Truncating the table will do nothing to his IDs assuming he's starting fresh.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Then my previous "*don't*" still applies. If IDs are special or well-known, then reserve a range at the start (say, first 1000 IDs) and *assign the ID manually for these records*. However, the auto-increment PK still should not be used for a magical sequential order.

Comment: @SandeshMgr I work in a mySQL environment and the script for me is `TRUNCATE [TABLE] tbl_name` This will delete ALL RECORDS in your table and reset the counter at 1

Comment: @nthCleaner, so I shouldn't use truncate command right? I did use it but nothing was the outcome. I am using workbench to implement the mysql database. I have tried all other commands provided from you guys and other people but still not working.

Comment: Could use vba -- Change the ID field to int, take off autoincrement and unique constraint, open the table in a recordset, then do a for loop and loop til EOF updating the IDs?  Or if you cant get away with removing PK constraint, add a new Int field, "New_Id", loop through it in a recordset with a for loop updating to new IDs, set that to PK, drop the PK constraint on original ID field, update original ID field to New_ID values, then move PK back to the old field and drop column new_id -- would work if that table isnt too big

Comment: @Acantud, Can I use this loop command process in putty or workbench ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with putty and i cant think of a way to do it in workbench.  Can I suggest another easier option, if you are under 60,000 records?  Export everything to excel, set the ID fields manually, then truncate the tables as the others suggested and re-upload.  If I was experiencing the same problem I would do that, or if it was too big, I would do the loop in MS Access using VBA. You can declare a recordset to your table, then use a "Do until myRecordst.eof" and "myRecordset.movenext" , changing each value to "myRecordset.fields("id") = myIntCounter", then increment the intCounter

Answer (score 0):

Truncate your table first and then execute this

```
   ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: why on earth would you truncate the table?

Comment: @rakeshjain, How can I truncate the table. Can you help me please

Comment: @SandeshMgr You can just use DELETE FROM tablename command to delete all the existing rows and then reset auto increment to 1 using above command so that new entries now will start from 1

Comment: @rakeshjain, If I deleted all my records and insert the command ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 then it works. However all my files will be deleted  isn't? So there is no way that I can just update the list not manually.

Comment: @SandeshMgr You mean to say you want to preserve your old rows and have their ids renewed starting from 1 and then the auto-increment field should take the values from there on?

Answer (score 0):

You should truncate the table to reseed it properly and not just use alter table

Comment: How can I truncate the table. Can you help me please

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE tablename

Answer (score 0):

(tldr; it's usually better not to worry about the density or sequential order an auto-increment column.)

It is *not possible*<sup>1</sup> to use an AUTO_INCREMENT to automatically fill in values less than MAX(ID).

However, the auto increment ID can be reset *if* existing IDs are updated. The compacting phase is required because [MySQL does *not* allow "filling in gaps" via an auto-increment column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923132/2864740).

1. [*Compact* the existing IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5437720/2864740), like so:

   ```
   SET @i := 0;
   UPDATE t id = @i := (@i+1)
   ```

   **Important:** Make sure that all relational usage is identified in the form of Foreign Key relations with CASCADE ON UPDATE *before* this is done or the data may become irreversibly corrupted.
2. Assign the auto-ID see to the *maximum*<sup>1</sup> ID value after compacting:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE t AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t)
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup> Per the AUTO_INCREMENT documentation in [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html):

> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to the value that is currently in use .. if the value is less than or equal to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reset to the current maximum AUTO_INCREMENT column value plus one.

The rule means that it is not possible to set the increment ID *lower* than an already used ID; in addition, manually assigning a value higher will automatically *raise* the AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Comment: @SandeshMgr `@i` is a variable called `@i`. This odd UPDATE syntax is just a common way of performing this task because MySQL lacks a proper ROW_NUMBER-like view operator and this approach (of a "side effect increment of a variable during the update") is easier than introducing outside number tables.

Comment: SET @i := 0
UPDATE files id = @i := (@i+1) Still doesn't work. @user2864740. It does accepts SET @i := 0 this command but not UPDATE files id = @i := (@i+1), gives me errors.

Comment: @SandeshMgr Whoops, there needs to be a `;` after the SET statement or else it will be a syntax error. I've updated the post.

Comment: @SandeshMgr To just display the *sequential number* of the record, that should be done from code with an ORDER BY in the SQL, instead of messing with the ID field.

Comment: I wanted the list to reset again starting from 1. I was doing some testing on some of the function therefore there were few rows created therefore I had to download these ones. Now, I want the list of number to go again from 1 keeping some records which are already in the table.

Comment: @SandeshMgr That is **not possible** with auto incremenet, as per the links I've included. You must manually assign ID's *lower* than the current max(ID) value.

Comment: @SandeshMgr Using the compacting approach above *with* proper FK/relational updates is the "best" that can be done automatically. However, I highly recommend *not* viewing auto-increment IDs as a dense rank, because this is *not* their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and sometimest fastest) way is to remove column and add it back. Updating column may screw up indexes or make a mess with values. Droping whole table got no sense. But remember that if other columns refer to that ids you can damage your app.