# How to reset id from database table in java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, reset

What I want to do is reset id from my database table.

Example, my table is:

```
id         data
1          Tony
3          Johnny
5          Julia
```

I want to reset the id become like this:

```
id         data
1          Tony
2          Johnny
3          Julia
```

How can I do it using mysql query in Java? Help me please.

Comment: In MySQL, there is no such thing as resetting primary keys, you have to do it manually. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key.

Comment: You cannot generate gap-less ids.  Don't do it. Why are you interested in a gap-less list of primary key values?

Answer (score 0):

It's a common misbelief that the `id` field should "fill the gaps". The `id` field is just for attaching a *unique id* to an entity, nothing more. MySQL's *incremental id* algorithm is very simple. It stores the last used `id` value, then adds 1 to it, when you insert a new row.

I suggest you to use Java's [`java.util.UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class for generating new `id`'s, because *incremental id* is vulnerable to hacks.

Usage:

```java
String id = UUID.randomUUID();
```