# MySQL Update command with auto increment

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `users_items`. In this table there are 3 columns. 1 of them is called `id`. There are like 100.000 - 150.000 data in this table. `id` is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

I want to reset all id's to 0 and than replace with numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 continue like that.

Comment: you want to insert your own id for each row?

Comment: And you want to keep the data doing this?

Comment: I want to keep data but only change id's for example 108843 make it 1 and make next one 2 like that

Comment: [Try this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-reset-auto-increment) you may find something

Comment: While it is clear what you want to do, try to put questions in the form of a question.  Just a heads up.  In specific with your question, there are a lot of factors to consider in doing that.  I would back up the table before you do anything like this to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to make all of them 0 at the same time, as you can't have duplicates for the PK.

Create a copy of the table using phpMyAdmin or any tool you want or using SQL queries.

Then delete all data from the original table using:

```
DELETE users_items
```

Or:

```
TRUNCATE users_items
```

Then reset auto increment using:

```
ALTER TABLE users_items AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

If you used `TRUNCATE` then you won't have to reset the auto increment counter.

After this you can use `SELECT` and `INSERT` to get the data from the copied table back to this one:

```
INSERT INTO users_items (col2, col3...) SELECT col2, col3,... FROM users_items_copy
```

(Note: the id column was not touched while selecting and inserting rows.)

Comment: Just drop a comment if anything :-)

Comment: But sir There are data like 150k I can't write insert into command for all of them :D

Comment: The insert is using a select. It will select all the data from the table copy and insert them into the current one by itself. Just that one command will do all the work.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

To start from one  simply do the following:

```
  ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

IF need reference use following links:

altering table:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Auto increament/Reset primary key:
[Reorder / reset auto increment primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key)

Mysql reset autoincreament:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-reset-auto-increment

Comment: Thanks for repyling but I want to reset auto_increment its correct but I want to apply auto_increment to all rows.