# Is it possible to make primary keys always be 1, 2, .., n even if you delete one of them?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

Through pure SQL statements for creating a table, is it possible to make one with primary keys that auto-increment from `1`, and also reset themselves to the form `1, 2, ..., n` if one is deleted?

For example, if my table `cool_dudes` has rows

```
id    |     name 
------------------------
 1        "John Skeet"
 2        "Douglas Crockford"
 3        "Steve Ballmer"
 4        "Bjarne Stroustrup" 
 5        "Home Simpson"
```

and I delete Steve Ballmer, then it becomes

```
id    |     name 
------------------------
 1        "John Skeet"
 2        "Douglas Crockford"
 3        "Bjarne Stroustrup"
 4        "Homer Simpson"
```

and any tables that have columns referencing `cool_dudes.id` then those columns are updated accordingly.

Comment: What for? And correct all foreign keys too. It will be very costly.

Comment: Short answer: yes it's possible. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key The real question is why you would want to do this.

Comment: Don't do that! Don't mess with the auto-increment columns! Use a `timestamp` to indicate order.

Comment: This is only possible with a trigger.  However, there is no reason to reset the values of primary keys once they have been created.

Comment: **This is a *very* bad idea.** It is possible, but then again, so is jumping off a plain without a parachute...