# MySQL | primary key needs resetting

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a table which stores the ID of support cases using the primary key (column name = caseid).

I have now got to about 100,000 caseid and the number is just too big. I wish to somehow start from a lower number such as 1000.

How do I achieve something like this by not having to delete/archive existing records and not having to change the unique caseid's to another column (keep it as the primary key column)

Comment: please share table structure.

Comment: Basically `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000`. However, with InnoDB, you cannot set the new index to a value equal to or lower than the current highest used index. If that's your case, the only way would be to `TRUNCATE TABLE tablename` but that will, of course, purge all data from it.

Comment: If you have so many records, then your auto_increment id must cover the entire range. I do not see any way to do what you would like to achive.

Comment: Just use `ALTER TABLE <tablename> AUTO_INCREMENT = <number>`

Comment: "and the number is just too big" - please elaborate the exact use case where the number is "too big". It's not "too big" for a link e.g. I guess you mean "too many digits to type"; in that case: who's typing the digits, when, where and how?

Comment: altering increment number would start overriding existing records though..

Comment: Altering the auto increment number can't lead to overriding existing values: this is the primary key, all values are unique in the table.

Comment: What is your table structure? (the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Reorder/Reset auto increment primary key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key)

Comment: Aesthetic decisions are not a good criteria to tamper with the db

Comment: Solution to your problem is trivial. You simply **do nothing**. It's not what you want to read, but that's the only viable solution. Hacks like resetting PK or even reusing PK values will lead to problems. Just leave it alone.

Comment: Add a new column for arbitrary id's and leave the primary key alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset `Primary Key`, you can follow below steps:

1. Create `temporary table` with structure same as `main table`. Let's say table name is `tbl_cases`

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tbl_cases_tmp LIKE tbl_cases;
   ALTER TABLE tbl_cases_tmp ADD old_caseid int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
   ```
2. `DUMP` all data from `tbl_cases` to `tbl_cases_tmp`. `caseid` will be stored in `old_caseid` column.

   ```
   INSERT INTO tbl_cases_tmp (name, summary, old_caseid)
   SELECT name, summary, caseid FROM tbl_cases;
   ```
3. For any other tables having references to `tbl_cases`. Let's say `tbl_reference`

   ```
   UPDATE tbl_reference tr 
   JOIN tbl_cases_tmp tc
   ON tr.caseid = tc.old_caseid
   SET tr.caseid = tc.caseid;
   ```

Before using Steps 4 and 5, ensure your tables `tbl_cases_tmp` and all references are properly updated.

4. Drop `tbl_cases`

   ```
   DROP table tbl_cases;
   ```
5. Rename `tbl_cases_tmp` to `tbl_cases`

   ```
   RENAME TABLE tbl_cases_tmp TO tbl_cases;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What about find lowest id and subtract its Value from all ids?

Then you'll be able to re-set the id to a lower number

Edit:

This suppose that there are unused ids and no recods related to them

Comment: What about all the other tables referencing this id? This is likely to break data consistency.

Comment: @Jocelyn Naturally it needs to modify all ids into all tables. Every id Will always be unique

Answer (score 0):

In case your problem is with conveying the caseid e.g. from the customer via phone to the help desk you might consider leaving the actual case id as-is but change the alphabet/set of digits when showing it.
E.g. switch from decimal to hexadecimal and you've increased the range of values that can be displayed as four digits/characters from 9999 to 65535 (hex:ffff).
Now consider a different set of digits like `3479ACEFHJKLMNPRTUVWXY`* and the range of numbers that can be displayed using only four digits/characters increases quite a lot.

```
<?php
echo getCode(234255), "\r\n"; // up until "here": four digits
echo getCode(234256), "\r\n"; // ok, now it's five
echo getCode(5100000), "\r\n"; // but stays five until > 5 millions

function toBase(/* positiv integer*/ $n, array $alphabet) {
    $retval = '';
    do {
        $retval = $alphabet[ $n%count($alphabet) ] . $retval;
        $n = intval( $n / count($alphabet) );
    }
    while( ($n=intval($n)) > 0);
    return $retval;
}

function getCode(/*int*/ $caseid) {
    static $alphabet = ['3','4','7','9','A','C','E','F','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','R','T','U','V','W','X','Y'];
    return toBase($caseid, $alphabet);
}
```

prints

```
YYYY
43333
YTYAA
```

*) an alphabet containing only unambiguous characters.