# How to ensure no gaps in auto_increment numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem case with auto_incrementing, this is my table i have first it was so smooth to incrementing id*

```
id*      name
1        name1
2        name2
3        name3
4        name4
5        name5
6        name6
```

but when I delete a record and insert a new record the id starts from 7.

```
id*      name
1        name1
2        name2
3        name3
5        name5
6        name6
7        name7
```

this is what i want to make:

```
id*      name
1        name1
2        name2
3        name3
4        name7
5        name5
6        name6
```

I would like a solution where every number is filled in, so if I delete a row the next autoinc number will be the number that I deleted not the next number higher.

Comment: No there is no way to easily reinit autoincrement items also it not so good idea, but there is some solution's present check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key

Comment: What you are trying to do is not really safe. Imagine you have another table with foreign key this 'id'. In case you delete a row and try to swift all other rows one up, the relation between the tables will break.

Comment: Never mess with the aut-increment!

Comment: I'd suggest thinking about why you think you want this, and maybe asking a question about that.

Comment: What is your goal behind this?!

Comment: agree with @Stavros .It's not a good way to do so you can create one another column like duplicate_id and you can set the data like same you want but you always need to check the last biggest value and insert biggest+1 value.auto-increment cant give you as you want .

Comment: It is not recommended to mess with Auto Increment . Just imagine if you had to re order 1million of entries , what would be the performance of the program . I would agree with the approach of @CollinD .

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It is non standard and there is probably a differnt solution that would work better.  Try to explain why you need to do this

Answer (score 7):

First off, it's completely **fine** to have these gaps. There **is no problem**. It's just your OCD that forces you to think these numbers have to follow a pattern - they DON'T.

- `auto_increment` is not a PHP feature, it's MySQL feature
- `auto_increment` ensures every row gets a **unique** number. It doesn't deal with sequential numbers
- `auto_increment` works safely in concurrent environment - that means there are a lot of users connecting to MySQL and doing stuff, and all of them have to be able to deal with the database and not get the same id for identifying a row. This is done through a rather complex process and this is one of the reasons why `auto_increment` yields gaps
- `auto_increment` is used by `InnoDB` for physical organization of records on disk - it uses the feature of `auto_increment` and that one is producing a number that's larger than previous (that's what it does, larger than previous, not sequential). Using this, a b-tree is constructed and records are written in sequence on the hard drive. Tampering with `auto_increment` makes `InnoDB` rebalance the tree. It means it goes through records and recreates the index if you mess with it - that's something you don't want. Ever

When you think about it, what do you even get with sequential numbers? Nothing really, except your brain probably hurts less because there's some imaginary order.

For sequential numbers, use triggers to create them. `auto_increment` has one job and one job only - to produce **unique** numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get something that looks like a list, I suggest you leave the field "ID" as is and add another field to use for names sorted numerically.

Anyway, you can get the same result with just a query like this:

```
SELECT name, @Rk := @Rk+1 AS Rank
FROM mynamestable, (Select @Rk := 0) AS Rk
```

Edit:
This query will return all records in the field `name` from the table `mynamestable` and also a column (named `Rank`) that will be a numeric incremental (starting from 1) so the result will be something like:

```
name    Rank
Name1    1
Name2    2
Name3    3
```

Comment: Hi Can you explain in greater detail what this query is doing?

Comment: @TobyAllen I added a little explain

Comment: How does this protect from generating the same number for a lot of concurrent requests? I see no constraints, you apparently assumed there's always going to be one person connected to MySQL doing work. This is a completely unsafe solution.

Comment: @Mjh I pointed out that it's only a list. It returns only the current Ranking. This gives you the current ranking while preserving IDs.

Comment: So you agree it's not a real answer that will work safely in concurrent environment, right?

Comment: @Mjh No! If Ryanto needs only a list and he doesn't need to update DB data I think it's a good and safe way

Comment: Ok, so what you are saying is that you didn't read the part where the OP mentions **delete** and you provided an answer that yields an enumerated list. How is that related to the question, which clearly states: **how to ensure no gaps in auto_increment numbers**? I'm not trying to belittle your contribution, but it's not answering the question. If the OP tried to use it, and if anyone tried to maintain the value of primary key using your query, it would be **unsafe**. I think that you can agree with me that your answer isn't the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

for it you can use [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) after delete. Update all ids (decrease 1) which greater than deleted id

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_ids AFTER DELETE ON test_table
FOR EACH ROW SET UPDATE test_table SET id = id - 1 WHERE id > OLD.id;
```

also you must [reset auto_increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql) or write another trigger for insert, which update id to max(id)

Comment: That's not what he is after and that would destroy any link between ids on different tables   This is an awful idea even if it might solve the problem.