# How to Re-Sync Mysql Auto Increment Fields

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization, auto-increment

I have a table bigger then 15M rows.
It has an A.I (id) value and some records deleted for example 5, 2.000.123, 12.000.002.
And i want to fill blank id values with the next record.

I thought something like this :

```
$limit = 1000;
$id = 0;

while($id < $total_record){
    $results = $db->run("select id,mac from logs where id > $id limit $limit");
    foreach($results as $row){
        $id++;
        $db->run("update logs set id = $id where id = $row[id];");
    }
}

$id++;
$db->run("ALTER TABLE logs AUTO_INCREMENT = $id;");
```

But it takes loooong time (:
Is there any way to doing this fast and easy?

Comment: if "logs" table storage engine is MYISAM, try changing its engine to InnoDB

Comment: It is already InnoDB but thanks for advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Reorder/Reset auto increment primary key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key)

Comment: It seems nice solution. And sorry for duplicate question. Thanks.

Comment: Do you care what order the ids are in?  Are other tables referencing this table via the ids?

Comment: @PravinS - I can't imagine changing the Engine will help for _this_ task.

Comment: @RickJames - This table is alone at the database.