# MySQL skipping auto_increment values (Continued)

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

I'd like to pile on to the excellent discussion below as I still don't understand what is going on.
I use the Google Cloud MySQL

```
innodb_version  5.7.25
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
```

I upload records into a table keyed by an auto incremented primary key.
There are no other unique keys.
I'm the only user and I'm single threaded.
I notice sporadic gaps in the key similarly to those reported by others on this thread.

To experiment with this stuff, I used 5 CSV files that I uploaded in a batch; I dropped the table and recreated it after every experimental batch run. I uploaded all 5 files in the same order every time. I tried different table structures, different data.

In the manual, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html it says about "consecutive" lock mode:

*This lock mode ensures that, in the presence of INSERT statements where the number of rows is not known in advance (and where auto-increment numbers are assigned as the statement progresses), all auto-increment values assigned by any “INSERT-like” statement are consecutive, and operations are safe for statement-based replication.*

And I agree, records are consecutive *within the same upload file*. **But there are gaps between the uploads.** The gaps vary. One table skips 1 key every time, then stops skipping for a while, then starts skipping again. Another table skips 8 records every time, which happens to be how many records I upload in the first CSV file that the table saw.

I couldn't see any rhyme nor reason for the number of records skipped but, curiously, the exact sequence of skipping happened every time I reran my experiment batch (so it IS a computer!)

I read the proposed solutions (set the lock to the "old" 0; don't use auto increment; etc.) These are all fine but I DO want to use auto increment, yet this unpredictability makes me nervous. Does anyone know

1. What calculation the engine makes to determine how many keys to "reserve"?
2. When does this "reservation" happen, before the upload starts?
3. Is load data more prone to "key waste" than, say, a python program?
4. Is there a way to influence this reservation with info, table structure?

Many thanks!

Comment: Here's a quick fix to the auto_increment column skipping values
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18761446

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that can "burn" auto_inc ids.  You mentioned only some of them.  Here is a partial list:

- Dup on another column
- Server crash
- Deadlock
- `ROLLBACK` - either explicit or due to some outside force.  Check for errors after every SQL statement.
- `DELETE` -- hence `REPLACE`
- `INSERT IGNORE`
- `ALTER ... AUTO_INCREMENT=..`
- (and maybe more)

(I would need to see specifics about your SQL to discuss further.)

It is better *not to depend on auto_inc being gapless*.